# Mongo: Find in associative array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am having "player" collection and each document will looks like this

```
{
    "player_id": 20,
    "level_details": {
        "12": {
            "is_completed": false,
            "level_data": "oijoisdffs",
            "completed_on": 1428570153
        },
        "13": {
            "is_completed": true,
            "level_data": "lfsdfjfjg",
            "completed_on": 1428512384
        },
        "14": {
            "is_completed": true,
            "level_data": "oafodjfosf",
            "completed_on": 1318374857
        },
        "15": {
            "is_completed": false,
            "level_data": "sdmflskfmm",
            "completed_on": 1428938475
        }
   }

}
```

I want to fire following query on a single document,
"Fetch all level_details whose player_id = 20 and is_compelted = true and completed_on >= 1428512300 and completed_on <= 1428512500"

So, In the response I am expecting something like

```
{
"level_details": {
    "13": {
        "is_completed": true,
        "level_data": "lfsdfjfjg",
        "completed_on": 1428512384
    }
}
}
```

can anybody let me know How should I acheve this?

Comment: Are the dates being stored in the ISODate format?

Comment: @ZeMoon no, they are stored as strings :-)

Comment: Side-note: It's considered bad practice to have to have values as keys, would recommend changing your schema to include an `id` field in your object that acts as the `level_detail` object id, instead of having the id as the key.

Comment: Also, converting the dates to be stored in ISODate format will make them query-able.

Comment: I have added dates in human readable format, just for this question. Actually cmpleted_on is a time in milliseconds.

Comment: @Avinash: MongoDB internally stores dates as msecs since epoch. Hence, not using ISODate will have no advantages but several disadvantages.

Comment: @Avinash using mongo query key name should be accessible. Also I don't know why you construct  `level_details` sub documents like `12,13,14, etc.` here you should simple post `level_details:[{},{},{}]` as an array

Comment: @yogesh Even if I do the array of objects, then what will be the query to return is_completed levels between date range. Please let me know the query. :

Comment: @Avinash check my posted answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should change your documents structure as below

```
{
    "player_id": 20,
    "level_details": [
    {
        "is_completed": false,
        "level_data": "oijoisdffs",
        "completed_on": 1428570153
    },
    {
        "is_completed": true,
        "level_data": "lfsdfjfjg",
        "completed_on": 1428512384
    },
    {
        "is_completed": true,
        "level_data": "oafodjfosf",
        "completed_on": 1318374857
    },
    {
        "is_completed": false,
        "level_data": "sdmflskfmm",
        "completed_on": 1428938475
    }
    ]
}
```

Now as per your requirement you should find your results using two ways

1> Using simple [find](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) and  [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) as below

```
db.collectionName.find({
    "$and": [{
    "player_id": 20
    }, {
    "level_details": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "completed_on": {
                "$gte": 1428512300
            }
        }
    }
    }, {
    "level_details": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "completed_on": {
                "$lte": 1428512500
            }
        }
    }
    }, {
    "level_details": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "is_completed": true
        }
    }
    }]
}, {
    "level_details.$": 1
}).pretty()
```

2> Mongo [aggrgation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) query as below

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
    "$unwind": "$level_details"
}, {
    "$match": {
    "$and": [{
        "player_id": 20
    }, {
        "level_details.completed_on": {
            "$gte": 1428512300
        }
    }, {
        "level_details.completed_on": {
            "$lte": 1428512500
        }
    }, {
        "level_details.is_completed": true
    }]
    }},
    {
   "$project": {
    "level_data": "$level_details.level_data", // Finding only level_data
    "_id": 0
    }
    }).pretty()
```

Comment: can I get only level_data in the response?